# How to limit UIPickerView or UIDatePickerView values?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uipickerview, uidatepicker

So I have a `UIDatePickerView` through which I get the birth date of the user. The pickerView has options till infinite time (past and future).

**What I want is to LIMIT the uipickervalues from 1981 till present date !**

I **do not** want the user to select some option and then pop-up an UIAlertView telling that the option is wrong.

How can I go about this ? I just want to display values from 1981 and show values till present date & time the app is running.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`UIDatePicker` has a property for the `minimumDate` Setting this will disallow selection before that time. It also has `maximumDate` set that to `[NSDate date]` and it will allow selection up until 'now'

Answer (score 1):

For `UIDatePicker` you have [`maximumDate` and `minimumDate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIDatePicker_Class/Reference/UIDatePicker.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDatePicker/maximumDate) properties that you can use.

As for `UIPickerView` - you are its data provider and you can fully decide, what to put in there and in what form. See its [reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html).